# MPI master process convergence loop

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to write a MPI program that simulates temperature flow throughout a grid to reach equilibrium.  I have already written a serial version as well as parallel versions using openMP pthreads and cuda.

My goal is to parallelize a for loop that is calculating updated temperature values for a 1 dimensional array.  The code I have to do the parallel part is here (all other variables are initialized above):

```
int nproc, rank,chunksize,leftover,offset,source, tag1=3,tag2=2,tag3=1;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    chunksize = (boxes / (nproc-1));
    leftover = (boxes % (nproc-1));
    if(rank == 0){

        //init dsv
        for(int idx = 0; idx < boxes; idx++){
            temps[idx] = newtemps[idx];
        }

        int stop = 0;
        int iter = 0;
        float max_tmp;
        float min_tmp;

        while(stop != 1){
            offset = 0;
            for (int dest=1; dest<nproc; dest++) {
                int chunk = (dest <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
                MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                printf("sent %d temps to process: %d\n",chunk, dest);
                offset = offset + chunk;
            }
            for (int dest=1; dest<nproc; dest++) {
                int chunk = (dest <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
                MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                MPI_Recv(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                printf("received %d temps from process: %d\n",chunk, dest);
                printf("status: %d\n",status.MPI_TAG);

            }

            max_tmp = -10000;
            min_tmp =  10000;
            for(idx = 0; idx < boxes; idx++){
                temps[idx] = newtemps[idx];
                if(newtemps[idx] > max_tmp){
                    max_tmp = newtemps[idx];
                }
                if(newtemps[idx] < min_tmp){
                    min_tmp = newtemps[idx];
                }
            }
            stop = (max_tmp - min_tmp) <= (max_tmp * epsilon);
            iter += 1;
        }
    }
    if (rank > 0){
        int chunk = (rank <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("received %d temps from process: 0\n",chunk);
        printf("status: %d\n",status.MPI_TAG);

        for(int j = offset; j < offset+chunk; j++){
            float weightedtmp = 0;
            int perimeter = 0;
            int num_iters = neighbors[j][0];
            for(int i = 1; i <= num_iters; i++){
                weightedtmp += temps[neighbors[j][i]] * mults[j][i];
                perimeter += mults[j][i];
            }
            weightedtmp /= perimeter;
            newtemps[j] = temps[j] + (weightedtmp - temps[j] ) * affect_rate;
        }
        printf("sent %d temps to process: 0\n",chunk);
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
```

My program however is successfully going through the first iteration of the while loop and finding the max value of the while loop (matching my serial version), and then sending the temps, newtemps, and offset variables to each process.  Here though my program stalls and the processes never print that they received the message.  The console looks like this:

```
[radeymichael@owens-login04 ~]$ mpicc -o ci changeInput.c
[radeymichael@owens-login04 ~]$ mpirun -np 3 ./ci .1 .1
sent 101 temps to process: 1
sent 100 temps to process: 2
received 101 temps from process: 1
status: 1
received 101 temps from process: 0
status: 1
sent 101 temps to process: 0
received 100 temps from process: 0
status: 1
sent 100 temps to process: 0
received 100 temps from process: 2
status: 1
max: 900.000000
sent 101 temps to process: 1
sent 100 temps to process: 2
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to find the mistake, but think I am lacking fundamental knowledge to use MPI.  If someone can help me find where my misunderstanding is I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you have a `while(stop != 1)` loop on rank zero but not on the other ranks.

Comment: I had it structured like that since I wanted the master process to check if convergence was reached and if it wasn’t send an equal amount of work to each of the other processes and then check again. Perhaps this is my fundamental misunderstanding, why would this cause an error?

Comment: the error is the mismatch between the master that will send several pieces of work to a given rank, the the given rank will receive exactly one piece of work. A typical fix is to `MPI_Bcast(&stop, ...)` so all the ranks know if they have some more work to do or they are done.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I think I understand.  So if I put the MPI_Bcast statement at the end of the while loop and add a while(stop != 1) condition for all the other processes then the other processes will stop since stop is now 1? Do I need to include any send or receives to make this work?

Comment: `MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation and must be hence called by all the tasks of your communicator. They should all use `root=0` since the condition is evaluated on (and should be broadcasted from) this rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, rank 0 is inside a while loop and will be sending the data till `stop=1` while all the other process will reach the `MPI_Finalize` after the last `MPI_Send` in the `else` part. One solution (as seen in the comment by @**Gilles**) is to add a while loop based on `stop` also for all other ranks and broadcast the `stop` to all the process by the `root`.

```
    MPI_Bcast(&stop,1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

See the below code.

```
int nproc, rank,chunksize,leftover,offset,source, tag1=3,tag2=2,tag3=1;

MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
chunksize = (boxes / (nproc-1));
leftover = (boxes % (nproc-1));

int stop = 0;

if(rank == 0){

    //init dsv
    for(int idx = 0; idx < boxes; idx++){
        temps[idx] = newtemps[idx];
    }

    int iter = 0;
    float max_tmp;
    float min_tmp;

    while(stop != 1){
        offset = 0;
        for (int dest=1; dest<nproc; dest++) {
            int chunk = (dest <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("sent %d temps to process: %d\n",chunk, dest);
            offset = offset + chunk;
        }
        for (int dest=1; dest<nproc; dest++) {
            int chunk = (dest <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            MPI_Recv(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            printf("received %d temps from process: %d\n",chunk, dest);
            printf("status: %d\n",status.MPI_TAG);

        }

        max_tmp = -10000;
        min_tmp =  10000;
        for(idx = 0; idx < boxes; idx++){
            temps[idx] = newtemps[idx];
            if(newtemps[idx] > max_tmp){
                max_tmp = newtemps[idx];
            }
            if(newtemps[idx] < min_tmp){
                min_tmp = newtemps[idx];
            }
        }
        stop = (max_tmp - min_tmp) <= (max_tmp * epsilon);
        iter += 1;
        MPI_Bcast(&stop,1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
}
if (rank > 0){
    while(stop != 1){
    int chunk = (rank <= leftover ? chunksize + 1 : chunksize);
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("received %d temps from process: 0\n",chunk);
    printf("status: %d\n",status.MPI_TAG);

    for(int j = offset; j < offset+chunk; j++){
        float weightedtmp = 0;
        int perimeter = 0;
        int num_iters = neighbors[j][0];
        for(int i = 1; i <= num_iters; i++){
            weightedtmp += temps[neighbors[j][i]] * mults[j][i];
            perimeter += mults[j][i];
        }
        weightedtmp /= perimeter;
        newtemps[j] = temps[j] + (weightedtmp - temps[j] ) * affect_rate;
    }
    printf("sent %d temps to process: 0\n",chunk);
    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&temps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&newtemps[offset], chunk, MPI_FLOAT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&stop,1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }

}

MPI_Finalize();
```